# pagination for table which having rowspan

Tags: pagination

I have got a Dynamaically created Jquery table which has got two columns
First Column : Master Table
Second Column : Child Tables.
It's obviously a one to many mapping where Master table row could have a rowspan of 5 which tells us it has got five Child tables.

I need a pagination for this Table. I have tried a lot. If I wanna show first ten rows and if the ten Row has got a rowspan of 10 then it hasn't got a td:border-bottom, then in the next page first td getting the value of second td which makes last td to be empty.

Please sort me this out. I need to have a border-bottom at each every page no matter what is its rowspan and in the next page alignment of td must be in the same way as it was in the first page.

Comment: did you find any workaround for this ? i am stuck with the same issue.